# MVC 5 Kendo button

Tags: kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have this MVC 5 project and I am trying to pass parameter with dot to Kendo button, like this:

```
(Html.Kendo().Button()
                    .Name("Add")
                    .HtmlAttributes(new { type = "button" })
                    .Content("<span class='k-icon k-i-plus-outline'></span> Add Line Parameter")
```

The javascript code to bottom page execute this:

```
$("#Add").click(function () {
    $('#wrapperViews').load('/controller/CreateParameter', id = @Model.dummy );
});
```

The code doesn't work for the param is "XX.DD" and return error

"Uncaught ReferenceError: XX is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.eval (eval at  (jquery.min.js:2), :12:78)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
    at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3)"

It works if I pass just XX or even if I set parameter manually like this:

```
$("#Add").click(function () {
$('#wrapperViews').load('/controller/CreateParameter', id = "XX.DD" );
```

});

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: assuming the value you are using is in the view model. Changing the value insertion from: $('#wrapperViews').load('/controller/CreateParameter', id = @Model.dummy ); to $('#wrapperViews').load('/controller/CreateParameter', id = '@Model.dummy' ); notice the quotes around the viewmodel value should work as that should prevent the code escaping incorrectly.

Comment: Thanks David. It works!